# Response with status: 200 OK for URL: null - Typescript Angular 2(SOAP Service call)

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-services, angular2-nativescript

I am getting response status as '200' but response as 'Response with status: 200 OK for URL: null' for the SOAP service call with my Nativescript application. I am using a post method and the sample code is as shown below,

```js
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Request, Response, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PaymentsService {

private body: string = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<HelloWorld xmlns="http://bernera.zapto.org/" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`;

private result;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

callSOAP() {

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'POST');
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'X-Custom-Header');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3004');

this.http.post('http://bernera.zapto.org/astronomy/astronomy.asmx',
  this.body,
  { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(
  data => this.result = data,
  err => this.logError(err),
  () => console.log('Call complete')
  );

alert('result ' + this.result);
}

logError(err) {
console.error('There was an error: ' + err.statusText);
alert('There was an error: ' + err.statusText);
}

}
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, then `alert('result ' + this.result);` isn't waiting for the result to com back (async) from the SOAP server, right?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you put in `subscribe` method is executed asynchronously after your server responses. In your case you use this.result before it's filled.

```
this.http.post(whatever_url, this.body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
   data => {
       this.result = data; 
       alert(this.data); // should return something
   },
   err => this.logError(err),
   () => console.log('Call complete')
);
alert(this.data); // <--- null, you hasn't received the server's response yet
```